# Multi-tentant model and nosql?

Tags: nosql, multi-tenant, document-database

When doing multi-tenant applications using a RDMBS I use `tenantId` columns in each table to indicate which tenant a row belongs to.

How would I do that in a DocumentDatabase? Let's take mongodb for instance. Is `DBRef` the way to go? Or am I stuck in the relational thinking? Or would you use something other than a documentdb?

(I'm pretty new to nosql)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a need for [Multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) under MongoDB you could use a different collection for each tenant. If the data is shared among all tenants I would instead keep a list of tenants for each entry like so:

```
doc: {
  _id: doc1
  ... // your objects here
  tenants: [ tenant1, tenant2, tenant17 ]
}
```

Then when I do a search or want a view of the database you should query with the relevant tenant:

```
db.mycoll.find({ someField : someValue, tenants : tenant2 });
```